linear search in 3x3 array using recursion
I am trying to search for a specific number in a 3x3 int array using recursion, but I don't know why the inner function never return a true value even though it should. How can I fix my code?

    
    
    public static boolean inner(int a[][],int i,int j,boolean found,int search,int c)
    {
        if(a[i][j]==search && j<3)
        {
            System.out.println("found at "+c);
            return true;
        }
        else if(j<3)
        {
            return inner(a,i,j+1,found,search,c+1);

        }
        else
        {
            return found;
        }
    }
   

I tried returning the position but it failed.

I think you should add some additional print statements for debugging.  The answer is fairly obvious.

where is the first index (i)  being incremented?

and, by the way, a[i][j]==search && j<3 is dangerous - it will first try a[i][j] and fail if j is greater than valid throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (and not test the limit)


In your stop condition you must check the matrix indices before you access its element, otherwise you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

If you have an NxN matrix then you must check that the indices are less than N-1 before incrementing the index in the recursive call, since indices start at 0.

You are missing another recursive call that will increment the index i.


public class Matrix {

    public static boolean inner(int[][] a, int i, int j, int search) {
        if (i < a.length && j < a[0].length && a[i][j] == search) {
            System.out.println("found at " + i + "," + j);
            return true;
        } else if (j < a[i].length - 1) {
            return inner(a, i, j + 1, search);
        } else if (i < a.length - 1) {
            return inner(a, i + 1, 0, search);
        }
        System.out.println("not found at " + i + "," + j);
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};
        inner(a, 0, 0, 16);
    }
}


Because you are only search the first row. You need to search all rows and all columns, like this:
    public static boolean inner(int a[][],int i,int j,int search)
    {
        if(a[i][j]==search)
        {
            //System.out.println("found at [" + i + "][" + j + "]");
            return true;
        }
        else if(j < a[i].length)
        {
            return inner(a,i,j+1,search);
        }
        else if (i < a.length)
        {
            return inner(a, i + 1, 0, search);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

Changes I have made:

I have removed the found parameter, because you do not need to pass whether you found the item, because if you found it, you just need to return true, so found will either be false in which case you search for the next element, or, if you found the search, return it
I have removed your c value, because it makes no sense to count for an index in a quadrangular matrix
I have removed all references to found and c when the method is called
since you need to call inner by passing 0 and 0 for i and j respectively, we can assume we are in the bounds of the array, as long as we make sure we do not get out from bounds while calling it recursively
I commented out your println, because it's anti-pattern. If you need to return a tuple, then change the return type of the method to the appropriate type rather than boolean
the first case is that the element was found at the current position, in which case we return true, or we could change the method to return the coordinates
the second case is that the item is not found yet, but we still have cells in the current row, so we proceed calling the method at the next cell but the same row
the third case is that the item was not found yet, we no longer have unchecked cells in the current row, but we have a next row, so we jump to the first cell of the next row
finally, the last case is that the element was not found, no more cells nor rows are available in which case we return false, the equivalent to not found. If you change the return type of the method, then change this return to return null

